# Fix/Repair invalid Geometry

Tags: openlayers, geometry, geotools, oracle-spatial, jts-topology-suite

I'm loading a shapefile in an app through a frontend with OpenLayers and trying to save the geometry to an Oracle Database with Hibernate Spatial. The shapefiles that have valid geometry (validated with JTS in the backend) don't have any problem but those that have invalid geometry (self-intersecting polygons and duplicated nodes) are not saved. Is not possible to save invalid geometry in Oracle?

On the other hand I would like to fix the invalid geometry, I've tried this (according to JTS documentation):

```
 polygon.buffer(0)
```

After execute that code, the geometry is still invalid. Is there a way to fix an invalid geometry  with javascript (OpenLayers) or Java (JTS or GeoTools)?

Comment: At least there is this OpenJUMP thing that is based on JTS https://sourceforge.net/p/jump-pilot/code/HEAD/tree/core/trunk/src/com/vividsolutions/jump/geom/MakeValidOp.java. It is using older JTS version before the JTS move to locationtech.

Comment: You can use the turf.js with your OpenLayers application.  Use the unkinkPolygon method to validate/fix geometies.

Comment: @Mike It could help for the self-intersected polygon but I've to deal first with duplicated vertices (except for the first and last vertex of each ring) if not I'll get an error from the method.

Comment: @user30184 I've used but it doesn't seem to remove duplicated vertices from polygons.

Comment: At least the OpenJUMP QA tool that is in menu Tools - QA - Make Geometries Valid with option "Remove duplicated coordinates" did remove the duplicate coordinates from a polygon in my test. Perhaps the menu tool has some extra features.

Answer (score 1):

Deduplicating a polygon is possible, I use the following code:

```
private LineString deDuplicate(LineString exteriorRing) {
    ArrayList<Coordinate> outRing = new ArrayList<>();
    int nPoints = exteriorRing.getNumPoints();
    Point lastPoint = exteriorRing.getPointN(0);
    for (int i = 1; i < nPoints; i++) {
        Point p = exteriorRing.getPointN(i);
        if (!p.isWithinDistance(lastPoint, tolerance)) {

            outRing.add(p.getCoordinate());
            lastPoint = p;
        }
    }
    
    
    if(outRing.size()>=2 ) {
        if (outRing.get(0) != outRing.get(outRing.size() - 1)) {
            outRing.add(outRing.get(0));
        }
        LOGGER.fine(outRing.toString());
        return GF.createLineString(outRing.toArray(new Coordinate[] {}));
    }else {
        return GF.createLineString((Coordinate[])null);
    }
}
```

The other thing to check is that Oracle is picky about coordinate winding order, if you use the GeoTools Oracle data store it will rewrite polygons in the "correct" direction for you.

Comment: I'll test the code and let you know if it works for me. I assume GF refers to GeometryFactory. What is the tolerance value when you call the isWithinDistance method?

Comment: yes, GF is a geometryFactory and tolerance is a "small" value in projection units that you consider two points to be the same if they differ by less than that ammount

Comment: OK, I understand then I have to build a polygon from the LineString and then build a new MultiPolygon.

Answer (score 0):

There is a prototype JTS class called `GeometryFixer` [here](https://github.com/dr-jts/jts/blob/add-geometry-fixer/modules/core/src/main/java/org/locationtech/jts/geom/util/GeometryFixer.java).  Try it out and provide feedback on whether it works!